# Confusing text about Radioactive decay

Tags: calculus

I have a question about relative growth rate and relative decay rate. In my textbook I see this:

[image]

and

[image]

k makes sense in the first image. If the population is 50,000 and $\frac{dp}{dt}$ is 5000 then k is 10%. If the population is 100000 and $\frac{dp}{dt}$ is 10000, then k is still 10%. This makes the relative growth rate constant.

But the second image text is a bit confusing. On one hand it says "the relative decay rate is positive" represented by this:

$$\frac{-1}{m} \cdot \frac{dm}{dt}$$

if $\frac{dm}{dt}$  is negative, then k is positive. But then moments later it says "k is a negative constant". What is going on?

Comment: No, it says that $km$ is negative, and since we know that mass is positive, $k$ is negative.  The equations you cite doesn't even mention $k$.

Comment: I see what the problem is now.  $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is the relative $growth$ rate, and that's negative.  The decay rate is the negative of the growth rate.  Forget about the words and trust the math!  $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is the derivative of mass w.r.t time, and we know the mass decreases.

Comment: So they define k above as the relative growth rate in the first image, now $\frac{dm}{dk}$

Comment: @Jwan622 Did you soved your doubts? Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: @saulspatz give an answer, I'll give you the credit!

Comment: Negative growth is positive decay, and conversely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what your problem is. $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is the relative **growth** rate, and that's negative. The **decay** rate is the negative of the growth rate. Forget about the words and trust the math! $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is the derivative of mass w.r.t time, and we know the mass decreases.

Answer (score 1):

There is not contradiction since for k negative

$$\frac{-1}{m} \cdot \frac{dm}{dt}=-k \iff \frac{dm}{dt}=km$$

Comment: but it says the relative decay rate, k, is positive?

Comment: @Jwan622 Indeed $\frac{-1}{m} \cdot \frac{dm}{dt} $ is positive and assuming k negative we can write $\frac{-1}{m} \cdot \frac{dm}{dt}=-k$ and both RHS and LHS are positive, I don't see contradictions

Comment: you just said $\frac{-1}{m} \cdot \frac{dm}{dt} is positive but this is = to k right. So then if k is positive, how can k be negative?$

Comment: How does K become positive in your equation?

Comment: @Jwan622 As I noted, k is a negative value, say for example k=-3, since m is positive and dm/dt is negative (the mass is reducing) the equation make sense

Comment: I think the answer actually has to do with the fact that one is a decay rate and the other is a growth rate in my question.